# How do i correctly get an output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def function(file_count,results):#results contain r.name and r.result
    args = []
    for r in engine_results:
        args.append(r.name)
    table_line = ""
    for x in range (file_count):
        table_line += "".join([
          "<tr><td>Ex",
          str(x + 1),
          "</td> <td>",
          "</td> <td>".join([args[x] in args]),
          "</td> <td></tr>"]);
    return table_line
```

I want to print out for example

```
"<tr><td>"Ex1"</td><td></td><td>" A B C D E "</td> <td></tr>"
```

`A B C D E` being the contetnt of `args`, this method didn't work nor a previous one i tested `column[x] in args` where it just gave me the first letter .

Comment: So you just want the contents of `args` to replace "A B C D E"
and `file_count` to replace Ex1, Ex2, Ex3, etc?
Everything else in your print example you want to stay the same?

Comment: Correct each new line will contain the content of args(A B C D E) and Ex1,Ex2 after each iteration(new line).

Comment: Okay, I think I've got what you want. Adding answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking. This is what I did.:

```
def function(file_count, results):

    # Get a string that is each item in result with a space between
    arg_string = ' '.join([str(i) for i in results])

    # Set up templates
    template_1 = '"<tr><td>"'
    template_2 = '"</td><td></td><td>"'
    template_3 = '"</td> <td></tr>"'

    # Create a variable to hold your lines
    lines = []

    # For every file in the range
    for i in range(0, file_count):
        # Make the Ex0, Ex1, Ex2, etc. string
        ex = 'Ex{}'.format(i)

        # Join all the templates and the ex variable and the arg_string
        result = ''.join([template_1, ex, template_2, arg_string, template_3])


        # Append the result to lines
        lines.append(result)

    # Return every item in lines joined by a newline
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: nope could've done it that way if i wanted to but the content of result is not always 3.

Comment: What do you mean? function(1, ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]) produces the output you asked. Maybe I'm missing something